# How can I install sbt 0.7.x via homebrew after already installing 0.11.x?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, sbt, homebrew

I have already installed `sbt` 0.11.x via `brew install sbt`. The problem is, I also need to use 0.7.x, but I can't find a way to install it.

I tried `brew versions sbt`, but I get just a bunch of warnings

```
$ brew versions sbt
0.11.0   git checkout e2cdafd /usr/local/Library/Formula/sbt.rb
0.10.1   git checkout ed6327a /usr/local/Library/Formula/sbt.rb
0.10.0   git checkout acf6b3c /usr/local/Library/Formula/sbt.rb
Warning: Version of sbt could not be determined for 36d0c62.
Warning: Version of sbt could not be determined for d320664.
Warning: Version of sbt could not be determined for 0476235.
Warning: Version of sbt could not be determined for 5e51224.
Warning: Version of sbt could not be determined for ca753a3.
Warning: Version of sbt could not be determined for 1c9b260.
Warning: Version of sbt could not be determined for d0efd9e.
Warning: Version of sbt could not be determined for 9d78f97.
Warning: Version of sbt could not be determined for b9c7891.
Warning: Version of sbt could not be determined for f78bb10.
Warning: Version of sbt could not be determined for 5aeb38e.
Warning: Version of sbt could not be determined for 07cd287.
Warning: Version of sbt could not be determined for b84b3e0.
Warning: Version of sbt could not be determined for a82e823.
Warning: Version of sbt could not be determined for 7702e83.
Warning: Version of sbt could not be determined for 9909fd4.
0.5.3    git checkout e28616b /usr/local/Library/Formula/sbt.rb
```

I'm currently running homebrew 0.8 on OS X Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why homebrew can't find the right version, but you could run `git show $SHA` where `$SHA` is each of the abbreviated sha1's that brew couldn't figure out. Find the one where the commit message tells you it's updating sbt to 0.7.x, and then use that one.